# How to get your question answered if it is closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wondering, how could one receive an answer to his or her question if it gets closed?

Can one use a bounty to counteract closure? The feature to reword the question is not enough. I tried to reword and recreate the question, but was told that was not the proper process either. What is the appropriate procedure? There's got to be an appeal process.

Comment: Servy has the answer, perhaps you could explain where you feel the process is failing?

Comment: `"Yes, indeed this is a legitimate question that I would like to have answered"`  Just because a question may be *legitimate*, doesn't necessarily mean it's on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Protip: Do *not* delete and then re-post the question...

Comment: Just repost it later I guess </sarcasm>

Comment: @Coffee - that's the last thing they should be doing, unless you forgot the `<sarcasm>` tag

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Well now that you mention it, I'll append that fix  :P

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Part of me *commiserates* with these opportunistic newbies. Really feels their lament

Comment: `There's got to be an appeal process or some sort of procedure` There is, the whole reopen process.  If a question is in fact closed in error it is quite trivial to correct it.

Comment: `I've been answering a question before and 30 mins into providing the answer the question becomes closed and thus not allowing me to present the user with the answer they seek.`  That's the risk you take when you answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Re: `about one who is engaged in the question to answer it`  - you should incrementally edit the question. First provide a raw-minimum answer. Then keep saving the new answer it every 3 or 4 minutes.  At least if you're in the points game

Comment: Re: That's what I've been doing after that happened to me, but the difficulty is providing a thorough enough answer to not be downvoted, but out beating the competition as well.

Comment: @Coffee - again, I don't think that's good advice - incremental edits are annoying, how do you know when the answer is complete?  If you provide a raw-minimum answer, and go back to edit it, you also run the risk of getting downvoted in the meantime if your answer truly is that minimum.  Just provide a complete answer the first time.  If the answer gets closed while you're trying to do so, and it was a legitimate answer, save your answer off-line somewhere, cast a Re-open vote, and wait until it's open.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Touche , you are right.  Laziness oft yields downvotes... time for me to recoup. Thank You ! :-)

Answer (score 16):

You can edit the question such that it no longer meets the criteria for closure.  If you do, the question can be reopened, and then answered.

If you want an answer to a question that SO has considered out of its scope, then you'll need to go somewhere other than SO to ask it.

Deleting and re-asking the same question is not appropriate, as you yourself said.

Comment: What happens if the answer provided isn't the answer you seek?

Comment: @Demodave Then your question wasn't clearly stated; you should clarify it such that more accurately represents your question.  If your question was clear and was understood by the readers and you just didn't like the answers, you can downvote those answers to indicate that you don't think they're helpful, comment on what the problems were, and post a bounty to attract higher quality answers.

Comment: but you can't do all those if the question is closed.

Comment: @Demodave You can downvote and comment on an incorrect answer to a closed question.  You cannot post a bounty to a closed question, no; you would need to do as I suggested here and improve the question such that it gets reopened first.

Answer (score 12):

I do not support the feature request being proposed here, because there is no need for it.

**It is intentional that if a question is closed, no answer can be posted.** The proper way to regain the capability to get an answer is to **get the question reopened** (not reposting). You can do this by substantially editing your question so that it is fit for SO. It will be put into the reopen queue automatically. If it does not get reopened, chances are that your question is still not fit for SO.

Now, mistakes *can* happen. If the above procedure does not work and you are **absolutely certain** that your question being closed is a grave mistake then you can come to Meta provide a link to your question and argue for its reopening. Sometimes this gets questions reopened. However, you should know that most of the time questions are properly closed, and that ill-founded complaints on Meta can backfire spectacularly. (See above about being "absolutely certain".)

Comment: Chat can help too. If it is a c# question, hang out in the c# chat room for example. (important to check if they allow such requests in that room though).

Answer (score 5):

Servy sums it up very well. A last note from my side: **bounties are not a free pass that allows you to bypass site rules!**

Bounties are there to give you the opportunity to get your question answered by some advertising time. Your question will show up in a special list, that's all. All questions there should obey the site rules as much as others do.