# Why is my question repeatedly being closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [MacOS, Swift, Cocoa - how do i put my window in front of the screensaver, and full screen applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360045)

The question I am trying to post keeps getting shut down, and I want to understand why this is happening.
I was advised to post my question again in the comments of a related question, however as soon as I had done so, the comment advising me to repost had been removed, I do not understand why.

I presume y'all can see the history of my posts, and the conversations I have had in the comments, despite all of this having been deleted now?

Comment: am i wrong to think i now have the same question pending twice in two different queues?  should i do anything about this, can i do anything?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70360045) was posted and was open for approximately 7 hours before being closed by users with [close vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). It appears that two of those users used the closure reason "Needs more focus" and one user voted to close it as a duplicate of [macOS: how to create a view that is in front of EVERYTHING](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67151002).

This resulted in an [automatically generated comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360045/macos-swift-cocoa-how-do-i-put-my-window-in-front-of-the-screensaver-and-fu#comment124376092_70360045):

> Does this answer your question? [macOS: how to create a view that is in front of EVERYTHING](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67151002)

And a blue banner above your question which reads:

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. [You can edit the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70360045/edit)

You then [edited your post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70360045/3) and marked the edit as resolving the closure reasons. This added it to the [Reopen Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen) where it is currently pending review (again by users with [close and reopen vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) to determine if the current version can be reopened or not.

Up to this point, your actions were correct and in line with the help center guidance: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

At this point, you should have waited (or continued to improve your post through edits) until the reopen process had completed.

---

At some point after submitting your question to Reopen Queue you posted an [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70387045/15497888) to the [linked potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67151002).

> .mainMenu + 1 is apparently the same as .statusBar
>
> the raw values are 24 and 25 respectively.
>
> neither of these values are working for me, and i still cannot get my
> window in front of the screensaver, or full screen applications.
>
> [MacOS, Swift, Cocoa - how do i put my window in front of the
> screensaver, and full screen applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70360045)

This is not an answer to the question. For this reason, it was likely flagged as [Not an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81389/when-should-you-decide-whether-to-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/81392#81392) by users with [flagging privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). This caused it to go to the [Low Quality Answers Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). From that review queue a user chose the "Recommend Deletion" option with a [generated comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151002/macos-how-to-create-a-view-that-is-in-front-of-everything#comment124446134_70387045) which reads:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30609773)

I can see how this would be confusing guidance in this case. Since this comment does, indeed, encourage you to ask a question when what you really needed to do was wait for your existing question to be reopened. However, please understand that normally when someone posts a question in the answer field it is because they have not yet asked a question. This guidance is to get users to the correct place on the site, even though it was not successful here.

Regardless, your answer did not attempt to answer the question, so it was deleted.

---

Now you have [reposted your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408542/macos-swift-cocoa-how-do-i-get-my-window-in-front-of-the-screensaver) which is [not permitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284595). Forewarning, it is standard practice when a user reposts their question to close it as a duplicate of the previously asked question. This is a special permission as duplicate closures would not normally be allowed to be used for questions with no upvoted or accepted answers except in the case that is one of that users previous questions.

An additional forewarning, that by posting on meta your post is now subject to the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350). Your post is going to be viewed by more people than it would have been otherwise.

Comment: thank you very much, you have been very helpful, and i think i get all this now.  can i, or should i, try to delete my repost?  it is slightly more focused and detailed than my original post, if that changes anything..

Comment: You should remove your repost, yes. If your newer version is better then you can and should copy the edits over to the existing post.

Comment: thank you, deleted.  to the person who voted to close as a duplicate of "EVERYTHING" above, am i entitled to argue that my question is not a duplicate - to the very best of my ability (and i do have some skill, quite well respected) the answers in "everything" do not work, and i have tested this quite carefully.  inevitably i will be wrong somewhere, and there will be something that i am not understanding - or is not found in the proposed answer - that i must discover, in order to answer my own question.  have i any recourse against such votes, or is that just how it works?

Comment: You can reply to that user in the comments of your question and (respectfully) explain why you disagree. You can also edit your question to explain it is not a duplicate. However, as mentioned above, 2/3 close votes were that your question needed more focus (it has too many questions in one). So that would be the primary issue I would look at resolving. But your actions about that post should be contained to that post: either the question body or comments.

Comment: thank you again for your time - am not sure how to focus my question any more closely, it really is just the same as the "everything" post that claims to solve the problem, and as far i can tell my text sticks entirely to that one question, i cannot see where it is not focused...  however, i did not realise i could continue to talk to the voters in the comments, i took closed to mean closed.  will think about this carefully, and try and answer as exactly as i can, after some rest.

Comment: @JamesKnight Just to start, there are 4 question marks in that post. PS This site uses English. [help] [Help] [meta.se]

Comment: at phjilipxy - you do not make any sense to me - 1 - what is wrong with a question that contains four question marks? - 2 - what is wrong with my english? thank you for your time.

Comment: am not happy.  i put a lot of time and effort, research and all, into my question, and i seem to have been shut down by people who have not taken the time to read my post carefully, and who cannot respect me enough to explain why they are cutting me down.  perhaps i need to spend more time studying the way it works.  is it worth the effort?  the advice i have so far, on this topic, from this site, has been misleading, and does not solve the problem, and perhaps my question is too difficult to answer?  i will give up soon i think, and rtfs, find the answer myself.

Comment: professional sources have confirmed that Apple began shutting down these behaviours in version 10.13, and since 10.14 it is simply not possible to get in front of the screensaver. this is new information, as far as i can tell not reported anywhere on stack, and the closed "answers" to this question are out of date, and confusing, without this information.

Comment: @JamesKnight well, you can still post that as an answer to the duplicate link along with supporting references to make it up to date?